# Grab the latest updated file from the Amazon s3 bucket using file name as query and get the last modified or created file?

Tags: vb.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to grab a file from Amazon S3. There might be more than one file saved with same file name, for example:

- `file1.pdf`
- `file-1.pdf`

I want to grab the file which is modified or added most recently based on the file name.

Is there a way we could do this using Query Or any other way?

I am using VB.net.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example filenames (`file.jpg`, `file-1.jpg`), your application would need to list the contents of the bucket and then determine which object is wishes to access. It would then access the object with the exact name (key).

Alternatively, you could use [versioning](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html), where objects with the same name are stored "on top of each other". That is, they all have the same name (key), but are assigned different versions. When you access the object, it will return the latest version by default. You can also specify a particular version you wish to access.

You can also specify different Lifecycle policies for versioned objects vs current versions.

Using versioning would likely be a much easier option than trying to maintain different filenames for different versions of a file.

Comment: Versioning won't be working for me. Have to perform a comparison with the file names. I would like to try the first solution. Is there a way to get modified or created date of the s3 object?

Comment: [`AmazonS3Client.ListObjects (string)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html) returns a list of [`Amazon.S3.Model.S3Object`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3Object.html) that contains `LastModified` date.

Comment: Thank you @John Rotenstein I really helped. I am getting the list of objects and then searching the list of objects based on the search